# How to get contents of a file from certain tag

Tags: github3.py

I'm writing an update script for project, where remote code should update certain files according to provided version number.
For this purpose tags (releases) are created in github.
Now I would like to download these files as they were at the commit of a tag that beared the name of a version.

```
>>> repo = github3.repository('Piletilevi', 'printsrv')
>>> for tag in repo.tags():
        print(tag)

0.2.0
>>> for tag in repo.refs():
        print(tag)

<Reference [refs/heads/master]>
<Reference [refs/heads/support-0.1]>
<Reference [refs/heads/1.0.0]>
<Reference [refs/tags/0.2.0]>

>>> for tag in repo.tags():
    print(tag.as_dict()['commit']['sha'])

3322aa270ac921cd0d90cb7f543e8dd917fa3637
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just couple of steps from solution:

```
>>> for tag in repo.tags():
        if(tag.as_dict()['name'] == '0.2.0'):
            sha = tag.as_dict()['commit']['sha']
            print(repo.file_contents('package.json', sha).decoded)
```

Comment: By the way, you can more simply do `tag.name` instead of `tag.as_dict()['name']` and `tag.commit['sha']` instead of `tag.as_dict()['commit']['sha']`.